# Accessing a value in a dataframe with at[]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

With the following code, I am able to get the value of a specified column and row in a dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['Name', 'I', 'C'])
print(df)
row = df.loc[ df['Name'] == 'K2']
print(row)
c = row.at[2,'C']
print(c)
```

Output:

```
  Name      I     C
0   K1    386  5522
1   K4  28800  6485
2   K2   1204  3257
  Name     I     C
2   K2  1204  3257
3257
```

However, problem with `.at[2,"C"]` is that I have to specify the row number. On the other hand, the syntax of `row.at['C']` is wrong. I also tried `row.iat[2]` where 2 is the index of 'C' column, but that is wrong, too. How can I fix that without specifying row number?

---

Although `squeeze()` works as Corralien suggested, I found that it is possible to first find the row number and then pass it to `at`. That is `row.at[row.index[0],'C']`.

Comment: How would you imagine getting a specific value without specifying a row?

Comment: The `row` is one row only. I just want to access a specific column of that row.

Comment: `row.loc[row.index[0], "C"]`

Comment: But it is not guaranteed to be a single row. What would you do in case of `K1`?

Comment: Right. I mistakenly wrote an additional K1. I will fix it.

Comment: @mahmood. Use `squeeze()` before using `at['C']`. Check the answer below.

Comment: If squeezed, `at` isn't needed.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Even if specifying row number is mandatory (assume there are multiple K1), how can I write the row number as a parameter? For example `row.at[row_num,'C']`.

Comment: `row.index[row_num]` it is

Comment: [This is documented under "Combining positional and label-based indexing"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#combining-positional-and-label-based-indexing).

Comment: @MustafaAydın: I mean how to find `row_num` to use it later?

Comment: "how to find row_num" based on what, exactly?

Comment: Anyway, I found it `row.at[row.index[0],'C']`. In that example, `row.index` is `[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the row number but the row label which is not the same thing:

```
>>> row.at[2, 'C']
3257
```

Now change the index:

```
df.index += 10
row = df.loc[ df['Name'] == 'K2']
```

Now, your last `at` command doesn't work:

```
>>> row.at[2, 'C']
...
KeyError: 2

>>> row.at[12, 'C']
3257
```

`at` uses the row and column label not the position.

**Update**

I think you need to `squeeze` your dataframe to a series before:

```
>>> row.squeeze().at['C']
3257
```